# How to create an SQL bulk transaction using variables in Python (with SQlite3)

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am reading from an external file and inserting data into an SQL table. It is currently working but is extremely slow so I want to see if there's a solution to fix this. I have already tried a different method that did work however it caused other errors and I was advised that I shouldn't use it anyway (I will show this below).

I have looked at several solutions to making bulk transactions in SQL but I can't seem to find any tutorial or solution showing how to create bulk transactions with variables (that can change) rather than fixed data.

This is the method that I found online which works faster but just sends me sqlite3 syntax errors after a while instead:

```py
sql_transaction = []

def transaction_builder(sql):
    global sql_transaction
    sql_transaction.append(sql)
    if len(sql_transaction) > 250: 
        c.execute('BEGIN TRANSACTION') 
        for statement in sql_transaction:
            c.execute(statement)
            connection.commit()
        sql_transaction = []

def sql_insert(commentid, parentid, parent, comment, subreddit, time, score):

    sql = """INSERT INTO parent_reply (parent_id, comment_id, parent, comment, subreddit, unix, score) VALUES ('{}','{}','{}','{}','{}',{},{});""".format(parentid, commentid, parent, comment, subreddit, int(time), score) #the .format() is the part I was warned not to use however I can't seem to find a way to pass transactions to be executed in bulk otherwise
    transaction_builder(sql)
```

```py
#all this code currently works but it takes 1-2 minutes to read 10,000 rows in my external file however there are hundreds of thousands/millions so it's not very helpful haha
def sql_insert(commentid, parentid, parent, comment, subreddit, time, score):
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO parent_reply VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", (parentid, commentid, parent, comment, subreddit, time, score))
```

When using the method that works faster, I sqlite3 syntax errors (most likely due to the way it inserts the variables). In my current, working method, there are no error messages but it works very slow, reading 10,000 lines every 1-2 millions which is very slow considering the external files have hundreds of thousands/millions.

execute many attempt:

```py
sql_transaction = []

def create_table():
    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parent_reply(parent_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, comment_id TEXT UNIQUE, parent TEXT, comment TEXT, subreddit TEXT,
    unix INT, score INT);""")

def transaction_builder(variables):
    global sql_transaction
    sql_transaction.append(variables)
    if len(sql_transaction) > 250: #trying to only run the code below when there are over 250 insert queries
        c.executemany("INSERT INTO parent_reply VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", sql_transaction)
        sql_transaction = []

def record_existance(commentid):
    sql = "SELECT comment_id FROM parent_reply"
    exist_check = c.execute(sql)
    for row in exist_check:
        if row[0] == commentid:
            return True
    return False

def sql_insert(commentid, parentid, parent, comment, subreddit, time, score):
    existance = record_existance(commentid)
    if existance == False:
        variables = (commentid, parentid, parent, comment, subreddit, time, score)
    transaction_builder(variables)
```

> sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: parent_reply.comment_id

Comment: I suggest you print your SQL query after creation - it will likely show you what is wrong with it. Also I very much doubt that you will see any performance difference between those two variants - you will end up with the same SQL query in both ways.

Comment: @SergeyA with the first one I showed, it only runs the code but in bulk when there is more than 250 of it which made it faster for me. Also, nothing was actually wrong with it because the query was exactly the same, the formatting however was different and I was told that you shouldn't format variables in the same way as the first one anyway.

Comment: Nothing stops you from executing 250 queries of the second version.

Comment: Read about [sqlite3.Connection.executemany](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.executemany)

Comment: @stovfl after hours of trying to make execute many work, it doesn't. All it does is give me integrity errors for a unique variable even though I already check that it doesn't exist.

Comment: @stovfl Just added. Hopefully it's just something stupid that I did / forgot haha

Comment: @stovfl okay added and fixed that, thanks for pointing that out because I didn't notice. However that wasn't what was causing the error because it's still there.

Comment: @BlueCanary: The field order are **contradict**: `commentid, parentid,` should be `parent_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, comment_id TEXT UNIQUE`. And as `comment_id` is `UNIQUE` you have to guarantee these contraint.

Comment: @stovfl firstly commentid and parentid are just variables in a function and are in fast text and unique. I ensure this with my existance function as I check if they exist before adding them. Also, this unique problem doesn't happen with the slow method that works (executing each line), only with the executemany.

Comment: @BlueCanary: ***"are just variables"***: It's unlikely that variable `commentid` holds the value of `parentid` and vice versa. ***"doesn't happen with the slow method"***: **YES** it uses the correct order `.format(parentid, commentid,...`It's **working for me**, see [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/QuerulousMistyPoints)